# How to insert new value to existing class array? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, object

Sorry if the question is not clear enough. I got a class array in my main as below :

```
Character *character[100] = { new Player(001, 10, 5, "one", "type", "desc", "status", "knife", 10.0, 20.0, false, true, "Warrior", "M"),
                              new Enemies(200, 5, 0, "Snake", "Creep", "Normal Monsters", "Roaming", "None", 15.0, 23.4, true, true,"Poison"),
                              new Enemies(201, 7, 0, "Wolf", "Creep", "Normal Monsters", "Roaming", "None", 15.0, 23.4, true, true, "Bite"),
                              new Enemies(210, 7, 0, "Dragon", "Boss", "Dungeon Boss", "Idle", "None", 15.0, 23.4, false, false,"Flamethrower"),
                              new Enemies(*(Enemies*)character[1]),
                              new NPC(700,0,0,"Nero","NPC","Lobby NPC","Idle","None",0.0,0.0,false,false,"Lobby")};
```

And in my addCharacter function, i want to check the ID exists first before adding a new character. So lets say I want to add a new player. I want to check if the player exists first. How do I do that? Here is the code I tried.

```
cout << "=====================" << endl;
            cout << "Add new player[" << count << "]" << endl;
            cout << "=====================" << endl;
            fflush(stdin);
            cout << "Enter ID                  : ";
            cin >> insert.ID;
            for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++)
            {
                if (Player[n].getID() == insert.ID) //Error highlight under Player. Error:class "Character" has no member "Player"
                {
                    cout << "ID already exists in index No." << n << " Please try again." << endl;
                    system("pause");
                    break; //Exit the function loop                 
                }
            }
            cout << "Enter Level               : ";
            cin >> insert.Level;
            cout << "Enter number of weapon(s) : ";
            cin >> insert.NoOfWeapon;
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour. Anyway, I highly recommend *at least* something like a vector of smart pointers instead of a raw array (capping the size without even using it all) of raw pointers that you now have to manage.

Comment: `//<<<<<< Error is here` It would help if you included the actual error.

Comment: @user657267
Error : Class "Character" has no member "Player"

Comment: @chris I know. But my problem is not fflush(stdin)..Im just using that because its my school practicals.

Comment: @Student, If your school is telling you to use something that is undefined behaviour, I have to question the quality of it. Especially when that entire statement is completely pointless.

Comment: @chris Yes. My tutor did told us to use this before when the input overlapped.

Comment: @Student, Well I can confidently say that your tutor is wrong and should be notified so the bad advice stops spreading. *If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream
to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is
undefined.*

Comment: How about posting the *entire* function for `addCharacter`, followed by fixing the type of `Player`, which I assume is a parameter that *should* be `Character *Player[]`, but instead is declared `Character Player[]`. Once you fix that you'll need some major maintenance on your remaining code.

Comment: @WhozCraig Initially my array was not using pointer. So basically my array is just like `Character[100]={Character(value,value,...)};`. Now I have added a few more classes that is subclasses of the `Character` class. And since all subclasses uses the same `int ID` from the base class, I would like to know how do I get the value from the subclass's `ID` value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Player` is your class name. `character` is your array variable name. So you should test.

```
if (character[n]->getID() == insert.ID)
```

However, a lot of your array is going to have NULL entries, so you need to check for that first. Something like this would work.

```
if (character[n] != NULL && character[n]->getID() == insert.ID)
```

Note: use `->` to access member values from pointers (thanks WhozCraig for pointing that out).

Comment: Its a pointer array. That `.`-operator isn't going to do any good at all.

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig, I didn't notice that when I copied the original code. I'll fix it.

Comment: @TheDark Thank you so much. Can I know when do I use the `.` and when to use `->` ? Thanks for your time. Appreciate it a lot

Comment: You use `.` when working with an object or a reference. You use `->` when working with a pointer.

Comment: Also, to check if it is a Player, you will probably need to use a `dynamic_cast` to convert from your `Character` pointer to a `Player` pointer. This is a pretty complicated area, you might be better off having some other way of checking if a `Character` is a `Player` (like having an `isPlayer` virtual function that only the `Player` implements as returning true. Or not having all your `Characters` in the one array, keep a separate array of `Players`, `NPC`s and `Enemy`s.

Comment: @TheDark Yeah.. Thats the next problem Im about to face now..My practical need to use this dynamic casting

Comment: @TheDark Are you somehow free to help me check my project? I'll send you the whole project lol. Because I dont know how am i suppose to insert the new values as `Player` class